# App Engine Download limited number of entities

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to download a limited number of app engine entities, say, only 500. Is it possible to do this via the Python bulkloader API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the bulkloader API is designed to fetch all the entities or all the entities of a given Kind.

If you want to download 500 specific entities, you could rely on the Remote API to access the datastore remotly as described in [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html)

Answer (score 0):

Debugging transformation failures without downloading all entities is really useful. Here's my modification to the bulkloader, based on the 1.6.4 SDK:

```
diff -r 1/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py 2/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py
3562a3563
>                      'limit',
3667a3669,3671
>     parser.add_option('--limit', type='int', dest='limit',
>                       action='store', default=None,
>                       help='Number of records to download (for debugging).')
diff -r 1/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py 2/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py
1252c1252,1253
                throttle_class=None,
>                limit=None):
1285a1287,1289
>     if limit != None:
>         logger.info("Aborting download after downloading %s entities" % limit)
>     self.limit_cnt = limit
1424a1429,1432
>       if self.limit_cnt and self.limit_cnt <= 0:
>         logger.info("Reached limit, abort downloading more entities")
>         return []
>
1429a1438
>       self.limit_cnt = self.limit_cnt - len(results)
1431c1440
       while result_pb.more_results() and self.limit_cnt > 0:
3377a3387
>     self.limit = arg_dict['limit']
3429c3439,3440
                                                         self.throttle_class,
>                                                         self.limit)
3689c3700
             'rps_limit', 'limit')
3723a3735
>   arg_dict['limit'] = None
```